# Как локально подключить библиотеку что-бы потом выложить на GitHub

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Мне нужно подключить некоторую библиотеку, но проблема в том что на нее указан абсолютный путь что делает код бессмысленным к публикации на `github`. Как в среде `Visual Studio` Указать локальный путь на библиотеку относительно папки проекта?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В путях можно можно использовать макросы, например - `$(SolutionDir)` - папка солюшена, `$(ProjectDir)` - папка с проектом. Соответственно если все сложено рядом, то можно указать что-то вроде `$(SolutionDir)..\MyLib\include\`

Answer (score 0):

Я бы сделал так:

Создал новый репозиторий, залил туда библиотеку, в проект подключил под-модуль. Готово. Всегда когда кто-то будет клонировать, форкать репозиторий, под-модуль будет на месте. Ну естественно подключение по макросам, относительно `$(SolutionDir)` или `$(ProjectDir)`.